Replace Playground roof
The cedar shake roof of my kid's playground is falling apart. This is the summer I do something about it. Just not sure what the best way to replace it is. The roof structure seems to be in decent shape.
I had originally considered using polycarbonate sheets like for greenhouses. However, The playhouse is in the path of direct sun for most of the day. Something a little more breathable and shady is preferable. currently considering a custom canvas. What would be a reasonably simple roof design/material?
Some pictures below for reference



What would be a reasonably simple roof design/material? Seems opinion based to me. Metal roofing would be good, but a tarp can work well too, but so would new cedar shingles.

FYI, your "crossbars" are purlins or skip sheathing.

Also, look up how to properly put a ridge cap on a cedar shake roof. The lack of one probably has a lot to do with why so much water got underneath and rotted them out from the bottom.

I don't actually think these are rotten--just stained. A few replacements for the missing ones and a proper cap and away we go. They'll weather to matching gray in a few months.

Any roofing material can work. The problem with a question like this is there are all sorts of factors that come into play: aesthetics, price, durability, and ease of installation being the biggest ones.
I would go with white corrugated steel with a ridge vent. Not that hard to install, very durable, and won't retain much heat.
